# Date literals not working in batch apex?

Tags: apex, soql, batch, date

SOQL:

```
[SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE createddate=THIS_MONTH]
```

This query is working fine when it is called from button, but it is unable to filter according to the created date when it is invoked from a batch apex.

Comment: Are you executing the batch using the same user (profile)?

Comment: Yes, the profile is system admin profile.

Comment: Can you post your batch Apex?

Comment: Additional code would be very helpful here :)

Comment: code snippets is here:-
https://gist.github.com/chikpea/9da862c3a79eb7c66a1e

Answer (score 2):

Based on the test below, the THIS_MONTH **date literal does work in batch Apex**.

I took your code (that I presume is a contrived example) and added debug log output:

```
global class  RunBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        string query='select id from Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        list<id> accIds=new list<id>();
        for(sObject s : scope){
            Account acc=(Account)s;
            accIds.add(acc.id);
        }
        list<Account> accList=[select id,name FROM Account
                WHERE createddate=THIS_MONTH AND id IN : accIds];
        System.debug('list=' + accList);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

and ran it from the Developer Console:

```
Database.executeBatch(new RunBatch(), 10);
```

and got the expected output (of 2 Accounts I just created):

> list=(Account:{Name=New Account, Id=001i000000wF4mPAAS},
>   Account:{Name=New Account 2, Id=001i000000wF4o6AAC})

Comment: so is this a bug or feature(salesforce point of view)??

Comment: @asitm9 I'm saying I could not find a problem in the code you posted - it worked.

Comment: actually i am invoking the batch using a scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this month can you use

```
Date monthStart = System.today().toStartOfMonth();
Date monthEnd = System.today().addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth().addDays(-1);
```

and then in query:

```
where CreatedDate >= :monthStart and CreatedDate <= :monthEnd
```